# errors uploading app. Error ITMS 9000

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect

Im trying to submit my app to the app store, but am receiving the following errors (see image)

[image: Errors when uploading:]

I originally was going to make this an iPad and iPhone app, but eventually decided to just go with iPhone. It appears that my project is still making a reference to my iPad nib file, which i thought id deleted.

I can't find any reference to it in my .plist file (screenshot attached).

[image: .plist file]

Can anybody suggest why I'm getting this error still, and how i go about fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to by problem - in the project navigator, all my files were sitting in a folder named "iPad" and for whatever reason, iTunes Connect didn't like this.

Comment: I had a same problem but not using a storyboard. how can I resolved that problem?

Any Suggestions ..